# Kafka streams - First example WordCount doesn't count correctly the first lap

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect, bigdata

I'm studying Kafka Streams and I have a problem with the first example of WordCount in Java 8, taken from the documentation.

Using the latest available versions of kafka streams, Kafka Connect and WordCount lambda expressions example.

I follow the following steps:
I create an input topic in Kafka, and an output one. Start the app streaming and then uploading the input topic by inserting some words from a .txt file

On the first count, in the output topic I see the words grouped correctly, but the counts are wrong. If I try to reinsert the same words, the successive counts from the previous incorrect counts are all correct.

If I Looking the input topic dump with a consumer console, it's loaded properly and there are no dirty data.

How is it that the first time count wrong?

Example [FIRST DATA]:
(input Topic in Kafka)
hi hi
mike mike
test

(App streaming is running)

(output Topic) hi 12 mike 4 test 3 (casual counts)

[SUCCESSIVE DATA - Posting in the input topic the same words]

(output Topic) hi 14 mike 6 test 4

[NEW ATTEMPT]

(output Topic) hi 16 mike 8 test 5

and so on....

Comment: That sounds weirds. Can you reliable reproduce the issue? This should not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WordCount demo in Apache Kafka has [the following lines](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/wordcount/WordCountDemo.java#L54-L57):

```
// setting offset reset to earliest so that we can re-run the demo code with the same pre-loaded data
// Note: To re-run the demo, you need to use the offset reset tool:
// https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Application+Reset+Tool
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

This means that, when you restart the app, it will read its input topic from the very beginning ("earliest") *iff* there are no existing consumer offsets for the WordCount app stored in Kafka.  An app's consumer offsets expire in Kafka after a certain amount of app inactivity, the default is 24 hours (cf. the `offsets.retention.minutes` [broker configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs)).

I could imagine that the following happened:

- You experimented with Kafka some time earlier and entered test data to the input topic.
- Then you took a >24 hours break before resuming your experiments.
- Now the app, when it restarted, reverted to re-reading the input topic all the way from the beginning, thereby picking up older test input data and thus leading to "inflated" counts.

> If I Looking the input topic dump with a consumer console, it's loaded properly and there are no dirty data.

You can verify my hypothesis above by looking at the input topic again with the console consumer while adding the CLI option `--from-beginning` (see https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_consume).

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic yourInputTopic --from-beginning
```

This will show you all the available data in the topic "yourInputTopic" -- minus any data that might have been purged from the Kafka topics in the meantime (the default broker configuration will purge data that is older than 7 days, cf. `log.retention.hours`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually when I was testing after 24 hours (then new offsets), I was deleting old topic (I enabled the cancellation) and was recreating them from scratch for a new clean execution. The problem resurfaced. But now I've added the line streamsConfiguration.put (ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest") in the example code (not there before) and seems to work well. Maybe I've not solved with exactly this, but it works.

Comment: I had a similar issue a few weeks ago, but sometimes the counts were negative. Could that be caused by something similar?

Comment: Negative counts? That sounds like some other problem.  The issue described here should only lead to inflated counts (i.e. counts that are higher than they truly should be).