# Kafka Streams DSL API has published message at consumer without processing

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, stream-processing

I tried to run the below program using kafka version 0.11.0.2. I complied it and created a runnable jar, which is run from the server where kafka is set up. The input published to kafka through producer/input topic is obtained as such at the consumer/output topic, without applying the processing logic and I am not getting the word count.
(Kafka is set up with a single partition and replication factor as 1).

```
public class WordCount {

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String bootstrapServers = args.length > 0 ? args[0] : "192.168.65.11:9092";
    final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-lambda-example");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "wordcount-lambda-example-client");
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName()); 
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
    streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);

    final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
    final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();
    final KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

    final KStream<String, String> textLines = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input");
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W+", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
    final KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = textLines
      .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(pattern.split(value.toLowerCase())))
      .groupBy((key, word) -> word)
      .count();
    wordCounts.toStream().to(stringSerde, longSerde, "streams-wordcount-output");
    final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfiguration);
    streams.cleanUp();
    streams.start();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
  }
```

How do i get it to work? What could i be doing wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674296/kafka-streams-first-example-wordcount-doesnt-count-correctly-the-first-lap , please take a look at this question.